# My project references another project which references a 3rd party assembly. How do I set the assembly path for this 3rd party assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

My project A references project B. Project B holds a reference to a 3rd party assembly. Project A is located in another folder than project B and the 3rd party assembly (due to integration with another software). I know I could have the assemblies in the integration folder, but I would like to have them in my own folder where I have all the other assemblies together with an executable used to diagnose and setup the module.

I have subscribed to `MyResolveEventHandler` in project A in the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain`, and can successfully set the correct assembly path of project B. The problem occurs when project A calls a method in project B where the 3rd party assembly is used. Then it throws `FileNotFoundException` for that assembly, and it display the path of the integration folder rather than the folder I set for project B in `MyResolveEventHandler`.

I've tried `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@"pathOf3rdPartyAssembly"))`, it will tell me it successfully loaded the assembly in the `Appdomain`, but will still throw the same `FileNotFoundException` mentioned above.

How can I set the assembly path of the 3rd party assembly used within project B from project A?

---

**EDIT:**
 *Sorry, the problem was caused by a well hidden bug by myself. I implemented some dll hijacking countermeasures that were throwing FileNotFoundException. Actually when the correct assembly path for project B is set, this is also valid for the 3rd party application referenced in project B. Sorry for wasting your time... I can assure you I wasted a lot of time before asking this question, when asking the question, and after asking the question. Now I gotta move on... :) Thanks for all your suggestions! I will upvote both of you...*

Answer (score 1):

You can [setup a custom probing path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx) for your 3rd party assembly. Please note that this approach won't work with ASP.NET applications (they don't support custom probing paths).

Comment: unfortunately the integration folder is not a subfolder of the application base... sorry for not mentioning this in the question.

Comment: @jmelhus can you create a symbolic link to that folder? http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. After a lot of troubleshooting I found the problem in my assembly...

Answer (score 1):

try to use this inside the resolveEvent handler

```
return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(@"pathOf3rdPartyAssembly")
```

the pattern i usually use is

```
Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf Me.OnAssemblyResolveHandler
End Sub

Private Function OnAssemblyResolveHandler(sender As Object, args As ResolveEventArgs) As System.Reflection.Assembly
    If args.Name.StartsWith("assemblyName,") Then Return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(@"pathOf3rdPartyAssembly")
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

because the resolve event handler is expecting you to return the found assembly, or it will go on with the default searching pattern and then throw the exception, i suggest you to implement a stronger way to identify the assembly instead of using only the name like i do!

P.s. this is vb.net, but can be easily translated to c#

```
Private System.Reflection.Assembly OnAssemblyResolveHandler(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Name.StartsWith("assemblyName,")) { Return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(@"pathOf3rdPartyAssembly"); }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. After a lot of troubleshooting I found the problem in my assembly...